# php SimpleXMLelement parsing XML tags with multiple 'potential' attributes

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

As the title suggests, I have a question regarding the parsing of an XML tag that may potentially have multiple attributes (or none at all), and I'm looking for suggestions on how this could be accomplished; but first, I think a bit of background is in order.

I'm working on a PHP based [AIML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML) interpreter script called [Program O](http://www.program-o.com), and I'm in the process of migrating the code from string replacement functions (e.g. str_replace, preg_replace, etc.) to using PHP's built-in SimpleXML functions. So far nearly all of the parsing functions that I've created for the various AIML tags are complete, and working quite well, but one tag in particular is kicking my seat-warmer, and that's the CONDITION tag.

According to the [AIML tag reference](http://www.alicebot.org/documentation/aiml-reference.html#condition), there are three separate "forms" of the tag: One with both NAME and (VALUE|CONTAINS|EXISTS) attributes, called a "multi condition", one with only a NAME attribute, called a "single name list-condition", and the final "form", called a "list-condition", which is simply the CONDITION tag, with no attributes at all. The AIML Tag Reference that I linked to earlier has examples to all three forms, but with a lot of words in-between, so I'll repeat them here, in context with surrounding AIML code:

**FORM: multi condition tags:**

```
<category>
  <pattern>I AM BLOND</pattern>
  <template>You sound very
    <condition name="gender" value="female"> attractive.</condition>
    <condition name="gender" value="male"> handsome.</condition>
  </template>
</category>
```

**FORM: list-condition tag:**

```
<category>
  <pattern>I AM BLOND</pattern>
  <template>You sound very
    <condition>
      <li name="gender" value="female"> attractive.</li>
      <li name="gender" value="male"> handsome.</li>
    </condition>
  </template>
</category>
```

**FORM: single name list-condition tags**

```
<category>
  <pattern>I AM BLOND</pattern>
  <template>You sound very
    <condition name="gender">
      <li value="female"> attractive.</li>
      <li value="male"> handsome.</li>
    </condition>
  </template>
</category>
```

In the previous version of the script that I'm working on, only the "list-condition" form of the CONDITION tag was used, and while that's the most common form used, it's not used exclusively, so I need to be able to accommodate for the other two forms, as well. So my question is:

*How can this be accomplished in an efficient manner?*

I already have working code to parse the list-condition form of the CONDITION tag, and prelimary testing looks promising, in that it throws no errors, and seems to produce the desired responses (but only for the list-condition form. The other 2 forms fail with errors, for obvious reasons). The function is listed, below:

```
function parse_condition_tag($convoArr, $element, $parentName, $level)
{
  runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Starting function and setting timestamp.', 2);
  $response = array();
  $attrName = $element['name'];
  if (!empty ($attrName))
  {
    $attrName = ($attrName == '*') ? $convoArr['star'][1] : $attrName;
    $search = $convoArr['client_properties'][$attrName];
    $path = ($search != 'undefined') ? "//li[@value=\"$search\"]" : '//li[not@*]';
    $choice = $element->xpath($path);
    $children = $choice[0]->children();
    if (!empty ($children))
    {
      $response = parseTemplateRecursive($convoArr, $children, $level + 1);
    }
    else
    {
      $response[] = (string) $choice[0];
    }
    $response_string = implode_recursive(' ', $response, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "Returning '$response_string' and exiting function.", 4);
    return $response_string;
  }
  trigger_error('Parsing of the CONDITION tag failed! XML = ' . $element->asXML());
}
```

I'm still relatively new to using SimpleXML functions, so I may well be missing something obvious. In fact, I'm hoping that's exactly the case. :)

**EDIT:** Adding the function that I finally ended up with, as promised in one of my comments, below:

```
  /*
   * function parse_condition_tag
   * Acts as a de-facto if/else structure, selecting a specific output, based on certain criteria
   * @param [array] $convoArr    - The conversation array (a container for a number of necessary variables)
   * @param [object] $element    - The current XML element being parsed
   * @param [string] $parentName - The parent tag (if applicable)
   * @param [int] $level         - The current recursion level
   * @return [string] $response_string
   */

 function parse_condition_tag($convoArr, $element, $parentName, $level)
 {
   runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Starting function and setting timestamp.', 2);
   global $error_response;
   $response = array();
   $attrName = $element['name'];
   $attributes = (array)$element->attributes();
   $attributesArray = (isset($attributes['@attributes'])) ? $attributes['@attributes'] : array();
   runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Element attributes:' . print_r($attributesArray, true), 1);
   $attribute_count = count($attributesArray);
   runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "Element attribute count = $attribute_count", 1);
   if ($attribute_count == 0) // Bare condition tag
   {
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Parsing a CONDITION tag with no attributes. XML = ' . $element->asXML(), 2);
     $liNamePath = 'li[@name]';
     $condition_xPath = '';
     $exclude = array();
     $choices = $element->xpath($liNamePath);
     foreach ($choices as $choice)
     {
       $choice_name = (string)$choice['name'];
       if (in_array($choice_name, $exclude)) continue;
       $exclude[] = $choice_name;
       runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Client properties = ' . print_r($convoArr['client_properties'], true), 2);
       $choice_value = get_client_property($convoArr, $choice_name);
       $condition_xPath .= "li[@name=\"$choice_name\"][@value=\"$choice_value\"]|";
     }
     $condition_xPath .= 'li[not(@*)]';
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "xpath search = $condition_xPath", 4);
     $pick_search = $element->xpath($condition_xPath);
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Pick array = ' . print_r($pick_search, true), 2);
     $pick_count = count($pick_search);
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "Pick count = $pick_count.", 2);
     $pick = $pick_search[0];
   }
   elseif (array_key_exists('value', $attributesArray) or array_key_exists('contains', $attributesArray) or array_key_exists('exists', $attributesArray)) // condition tag with either VALUE, CONTAINS or EXISTS attributes
   {
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Parsing a CONDITION tag with 2 attributes.', 2);
     $condition_name = (string)$element['name'];
     $test_value = get_client_property($convoArr, $condition_name);
     switch (true)
     {
       case (isset($element['value'])):
         $condition_value = (string)$element['value'];
         break;
       case (isset($element['value'])):
         $condition_value = (string)$element['value'];
         break;
       case (isset($element['value'])):
         $condition_value = (string)$element['value'];
         break;
       default:
         runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Something went wrong with parsing the CONDITION tag. Returning the error response.', 1);
         return $error_response;
     }
     $pick = ($condition_value == $test_value) ? $element : '';
   }
   elseif (array_key_exists('name', $attributesArray)) // this ~SHOULD~ just trigger if the NAME value is present, and ~NOT~ NAME and (VALUE|CONTAINS|EXISTS)
   {
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Parsing a CONDITION tag with only the NAME attribute.', 2);
     $condition_name = (string)$element['name'];
     $test_value = get_client_property($convoArr, $condition_name);
     $path = "li[@value=\"$test_value\"]|li[not(@*)]";
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "search string = $path", 4);
     $choice = $element->xpath($path);
     $pick = $choice[0];
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'Found a match. Pick = ' . print_r($choice, true), 4);
   }
   else // nothing matches
   {
     runDebug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'No matches found. Returning default error response.', 1);
     return $error_response;
   }
   $children = (is_object($pick)) ? $pick->children() : null;
   if (!empty ($children))
   {
     $response = parseTemplateRecursive($convoArr, $children, $level + 1);
   }
   else
   {
     $response[] = (string) $pick;
   }
   $response_string = implode_recursive(' ', $response);
   return $response_string;
 }
```

I suspect that there may well be a better, more elegant way of doing this (the story of my life, really), but the above works as intended. Any suggestions for improvement will be gratefully accepted, and carefully considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I have not used `SimpleXML`, because imho `DOMDocument` is just soo much niceer and waaay more powerful. Both [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) have been available since PHP5.

I have created a simple parser class which parses the supplied document to get the conditions in different styles:

```
class AIMLParser
{
    public function parse($data)
    {
        $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($data);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $templates = array();

        foreach($xpath->query('//template') as $templateNode) {
            $template = array(
                'text' => $templateNode->firstChild->nodeValue, // note this expects the first child note to always be the textnode
                'conditions' => array(),
            );

            foreach ($templateNode->getElementsByTagName('condition') as $condition) {
                if ($condition->hasAttribute('name') && $condition->hasAttribute('value')) {
                    $template['conditions'] = $this->parseConditionsWithoutChildren($template['conditions'], $condition);
                } elseif ($condition->hasAttribute('name')) {
                    $template['conditions'] = $this->parseConditionsWithNameAttribute($template['conditions'], $condition);
                } else {
                    $template['conditions'] = $this->parseConditionsWithoutAttributes($template['conditions'], $condition);
                }
            }

            $templates[] = $template;
        }

        libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

        return $templates;
    }

    private function parseConditionsWithoutChildren(array $conditions, DOMNode $condition)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($condition->getAttribute('name'), $conditions)) {
            $conditions[$condition->getAttribute('name')] = array();
        }

        $conditions[$condition->getAttribute('name')][$condition->getAttribute('value')] = $condition->nodeValue;

        return $conditions;
    }

    private function parseConditionsWithNameAttribute(array $conditions, DOMNode $condition)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($condition->getAttribute('name'), $conditions)) {
            $conditions[$condition->getAttribute('name')] = array();
        }

        foreach ($condition->getElementsByTagName('li') as $listItem) {
            $conditions[$condition->getAttribute('name')][$listItem->getAttribute('value')] = $listItem->nodeValue;
        }

        return $conditions;
    }

    private function parseConditionsWithoutAttributes(array $conditions, DOMNode $condition)
    {
        foreach ($condition->getElementsByTagName('li') as $listItem) {
            if (!array_key_exists($listItem->getAttribute('name'), $conditions)) {
                $conditions[$listItem->getAttribute('name')] = array();
            }

            $conditions[$listItem->getAttribute('name')][$listItem->getAttribute('value')] = $listItem->nodeValue;
        }

        return $conditions;
    }
}
```

What it does is that it searches the document for `template` nodes and loops through them. For every `template` node it finds out what style the conditions are. Based on that it picks the correct parse function of the conditions. After looping through all the templates it returns a parsed array with all the info (I think) you need.

To parse some document you can just do:

```
$parser = new AIMLParser();
$templates = $parser->parse($someVariableWithTheContentOfTheDocument);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JPuBaE

Comment: While this function doesn't fit with the rest of the script, it **does** give me a direction to investigate, so +1 for that. If it does, indeed, lead to what I need, I'll be sure to mark it as an "answer". Thank you. :)

Comment: While I didn't end up using any of the example code posted above, it gave me enough of a "nudge in the right direction" to qualify it as an answer. I'm still fleshing out the code, but when I'm satisfied with it I'll post it here so that others may benefit. Again, my thanks, @PeeHaa.